# Using subprocess with a function?

Tags: python, function, subprocess

I'm trying to use subprocessing in Python, but I don't understand if it can be used with a function, because in the official Python documentation, the syntax of subprocess.Popen takes arguments, but I don't see anything that can be related to a function. Or is there another way to spawn a new process dedicated to a function without subprocess ?

Comment: Do you really need subprocess? What about threads?

Answer (score 5):

What you need is multiprocessing not subprocessing

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def my_function(name):
    print "My name is %s" % name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=my_function, args=('Yarkee', ))
    p.start()
    p.join() # this blocks until the process terminates
```

Comment: I tried multiprocessing, but it always conflicts with tkinter (used for the GUI).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. This may have what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

The python **subprocess** module can be used to call external programs like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

While multiprocessing, as mentioned by @Yarkee, is bound to a function so its probably what you are looking for.